# How can I scroll while I increase the size of a div with Resizable Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using the template of AdminLTE 3, I have a div which I can increase its height thanks to Jquery-UI resizable, the problem is that when I try to increase the size of the div the page does not go down while I expand the div.

I do not want to put a scroll bar on the div, I just want to make that when I increase the height of the div, the page will also go down automatically with Jquery or CSS

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#main_row_About_results").resizable({
         handles: "s"
        });
                
                
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.layout-boxed .wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.layout-boxed .wrapper, .layout-boxed .wrapper:before {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1250px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .content-wrapper,
  .main-footer,
  .main-header {
    transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 250px;
    z-index: 3000;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .content-wrapper,
  .main-footer,
  .main-header {
    transition: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-collapse .content-wrapper, .sidebar-collapse
  .main-footer, .sidebar-collapse
  .main-header {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .content-wrapper, .content-wrapper:before,
  .main-footer,
  .main-footer:before,
  .main-header,
  .main-header:before {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.content-wrapper {
  background: #f4f6f9;
}

.content-wrapper > .content {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.main-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main-sidebar, .main-sidebar:before {
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 250px;
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .main-sidebar, .main-sidebar:before {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar, .sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar:before {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .main-sidebar, .main-sidebar:before {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  .sidebar-open .main-sidebar, .sidebar-open .main-sidebar:before {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.main-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #555;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.content-header {
  padding: 15px 0.5rem;
}

.content-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.content-header .breadcrumb {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
}

.hold-transition .content-wrapper,
.hold-transition .main-header,
.hold-transition .main-footer {
  transition: none !important;
}

/*
 * Component: Main Header
 * ----------------------
 */
.main-header {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main-header .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-header .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.main-header .navbar-nav[class*="-right"] .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -3px;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .main-header .navbar-nav[class*="-right"] .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
}

.navbar-img {
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: .6rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

.btn-navbar {
  border-left-width: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.form-control-navbar {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

.form-control-navbar + .input-group-append {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.form-control-navbar,
.btn-navbar {
  transition: none;
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar,
.navbar-dark .btn-navbar {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar::placeholder,
.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar + .input-group-append > .btn-navbar {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar :-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar:focus,
.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar:focus + .input-group-append .btn-navbar {
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #343a40;
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar,
.navbar-light .btn-navbar {
  background-color: #f2f4f6;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar::placeholder,
.navbar-light .form-control-navbar + .input-group-append > .btn-navbar {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar :-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar:focus,
.navbar-light .form-control-navbar:focus + .input-group-append .btn-navbar {
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  color: #343a40;
}

.brand-link {
  padding: 0.8125rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.brand-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

[class*="sidebar-dark"] .brand-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b545c;
}

[class*="sidebar-light"] .brand-link {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.brand-image {
  float: left;
  line-height: .8;
  max-height: 34px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: .8rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

/**
 * Component: Sidebar
 * ------------------
 */
.main-sidebar {
  z-index: 1100;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
}

.user-panel {
  position: relative;
}

[class*="sidebar-dark"] .user-panel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4f5962;
}

[class*="sidebar-light"] .user-panel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.user-panel,
.user-panel .info {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.user-panel .image {
  padding-left: 0.8rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-panel img {
  width: 2.1rem;
  height: auto;
}

.user-panel .info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.user-panel .status,
.user-panel .dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-item > .nav-link {
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-item > .nav-link .right {
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .nav-sidebar .nav-item > .nav-link .right {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-link > p > .right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 12px;
}

.nav-sidebar .menu-open > .nav-treeview {
  display: block;
}

.nav-sidebar .menu-open > .nav-link .right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.nav-sidebar > .nav-item {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar > .nav-item .nav-icon {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: .2rem;
}

.nav-sidebar > .nav-item .float-right {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-treeview {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-treeview > .nav-item > .nav-link > .nav-icon {
  width: 1.6rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-header {
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-header:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding: 1.7rem 1rem .5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-link p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1099;
}

#blogArea
                            {
                                margin-left: 0;
                                /*width: 80px !important;*/
                                min-height: 967px; 
                                max-width: 80px !important;
                                width: 80px !important;
                                min-width: 80px !important;
                            }

                            #blogAreaContent
                            {
                              max-width: 80px !important;
                                width: 80px !important;
                                min-width: 80px !important;
                              }

                                    #main_row_About_results
                                  {
                                     border: 1px solid rgb(112, 113, 124);
                                     border-style: dashed;
                               
                                  }
                                  p:focus, h2:focus, h3:focus, a:focus
                                  { 
                                    outline: none !important; 
                                  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Amin bilding</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a href="main.php" class="nav-link">Summery</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="main.php" class="brand-link">
      <img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">ADMINS</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">Administrator Recons</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>
              <p>
                Dashboard
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="summery.php" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Admin Options</p>
                </a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
         
                              <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
                              <div class="content-wrapper">
                                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
                                <div class="content-header">
                                  <div class="container-fluid">
                                    
                                    <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Title</h1>
                                      </div><!-- /.col -->
                                      <br><br><br>
                                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right" style="margin-right: 14.6%;"><!-- style="margin-right: 12%;" -->
                                          <li class="breadcrumb-item">My Breadcrum</li>
                                        </ol>
                                      </div><!-- /.col -->


                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="max-width: 92.5%; width: 92.5%;"> <!--style="max-width: 94%; width: 94%;"-->
                                  <h5>Title Item: <b>(*)</b> </h5>
                                  <input type="text" name="blog_nameInfo" id="blog_nameInfo" class="form-control" required>
                                   <br>
                                   <br>
                                </div>

                                
                                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                                          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.content-header -->

                                        <!-- Main content -->
                          <section class="content">
                          <div class="container-fluid">
                            
                            <div class="row" id="main_row_for_blogs">
                              
                              <div class="col-lg-12 col-12" style="max-width: 92.5%; width: 92.5%;"><!--style="max-width: 94%; width: 94%;"-->
                                <div class="card" id="BlogEditorOptions">
                                
                                <div class="card-header">
                                  <h2>my title card</h2>
                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="card-body" id="main_container_blog_section">
                                
                                <div class="row" id="main_row_About_results" style="display: block; position: relative !important; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

                                <!--this is the div that it's resizable-->
  
                                </div> 

                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                             
                              </div>

                             </div>

                                  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                                </section>
                                <!-- /.content -->
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

                      <footer class="main-footer">
                        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2018 - MyBildingWall</strong>
                        <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                          <b>Version</b> 1.0
                        </div>
                      </footer>

                      <!-- Control Sidebar -->
                      <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
                        <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
                      </aside>
                      <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- ./wrapper -->

                    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->

                    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
                    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

                    <!-- Slimscroll -->
                    <script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

                    <script src="dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>

                    </body>
                    </html>
```

As you can see when trying to put the div with id = main_row_About_results higher using jquery resizable ui the body does not automatically download. I just want that as long as I'm setting the div higher, the body will also go down (scrolling) automatically with the div. Right now that does not happen. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the scrollTop as you resize. There are a number of ways to do this. Here is one example:

```
resize: function(event, ui){
  var rh = Math.round(ui.element.offset().top + ui.size.height);;
  var wh = $(window).height();
  var sp = $(document).scrollTop();
  var buff = wh + sp - 50;
  if (rh > buff) {
    $(document).scrollTop(rh - wh + 50);
  }
}
```

Calculating the Offset position and the current height of the resizable gives us a proper number of the mouse position in the document. Scroll Top and Window height gives us a good number to compare against. We add a bit of a buffer, 50 pixels, that can be adjusted as desired.

Once the condition is met, we move the Scroll Top using `.scrollTop()`.

**Working Example**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#main_row_About_results").resizable({
    handles: "s",
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      var rh = Math.round(ui.element.offset().top + ui.size.height);;
      var wh = $(window).height();
      var sp = $(document).scrollTop();
      var buff = wh + sp - 50;
      if (rh > buff) {
        $(document).scrollTop(rh - wh + 50);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.layout-boxed .wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.layout-boxed .wrapper,
.layout-boxed .wrapper:before {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1250px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .content-wrapper,
  .main-footer,
  .main-header {
    transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 250px;
    z-index: 3000;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .content-wrapper,
  .main-footer,
  .main-header {
    transition: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-collapse .content-wrapper,
  .sidebar-collapse .main-footer,
  .sidebar-collapse .main-header {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .content-wrapper,
  .content-wrapper:before,
  .main-footer,
  .main-footer:before,
  .main-header,
  .main-header:before {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.content-wrapper {
  background: #f4f6f9;
}

.content-wrapper>.content {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.main-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main-sidebar,
.main-sidebar:before {
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 250px;
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .main-sidebar,
  .main-sidebar:before {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar,
.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar:before {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .main-sidebar,
  .main-sidebar:before {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  .sidebar-open .main-sidebar,
  .sidebar-open .main-sidebar:before {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.main-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #555;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.content-header {
  padding: 15px 0.5rem;
}

.content-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.content-header .breadcrumb {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
}

.hold-transition .content-wrapper,
.hold-transition .main-header,
.hold-transition .main-footer {
  transition: none !important;
}


/*
 * Component: Main Header
 * ----------------------
 */

.main-header {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main-header .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-header .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.main-header .navbar-nav[class*="-right"] .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -3px;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .main-header .navbar-nav[class*="-right"] .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
}

.navbar-img {
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: .6rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

.btn-navbar {
  border-left-width: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.form-control-navbar {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

.form-control-navbar+.input-group-append {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.form-control-navbar,
.btn-navbar {
  transition: none;
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar,
.navbar-dark .btn-navbar {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar::placeholder,
.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar+.input-group-append>.btn-navbar {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar :-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar:focus,
.navbar-dark .form-control-navbar:focus+.input-group-append .btn-navbar {
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #343a40;
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar,
.navbar-light .btn-navbar {
  background-color: #f2f4f6;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar::placeholder,
.navbar-light .form-control-navbar+.input-group-append>.btn-navbar {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar :-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.navbar-light .form-control-navbar:focus,
.navbar-light .form-control-navbar:focus+.input-group-append .btn-navbar {
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  color: #343a40;
}

.brand-link {
  padding: 0.8125rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.brand-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

[class*="sidebar-dark"] .brand-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b545c;
}

[class*="sidebar-light"] .brand-link {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.brand-image {
  float: left;
  line-height: .8;
  max-height: 34px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: .8rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  margin-top: -3px;
}


/**
 * Component: Sidebar
 * ------------------
 */

.main-sidebar {
  z-index: 1100;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
}

.user-panel {
  position: relative;
}

[class*="sidebar-dark"] .user-panel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4f5962;
}

[class*="sidebar-light"] .user-panel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.user-panel,
.user-panel .info {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.user-panel .image {
  padding-left: 0.8rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-panel img {
  width: 2.1rem;
  height: auto;
}

.user-panel .info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.user-panel .status,
.user-panel .dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-item>.nav-link {
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-item>.nav-link .right {
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .nav-sidebar .nav-item>.nav-link .right {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-link>p>.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 12px;
}

.nav-sidebar .menu-open>.nav-treeview {
  display: block;
}

.nav-sidebar .menu-open>.nav-link .right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.nav-sidebar>.nav-item {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar>.nav-item .nav-icon {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: .2rem;
}

.nav-sidebar>.nav-item .float-right {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-treeview {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-treeview>.nav-item>.nav-link>.nav-icon {
  width: 1.6rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-header {
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-header:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding: 1.7rem 1rem .5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-sidebar .nav-link p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1099;
}

#blogArea {
  margin-left: 0;
  /*width: 80px !important;*/
  min-height: 967px;
  max-width: 80px !important;
  width: 80px !important;
  min-width: 80px !important;
}

#blogAreaContent {
  max-width: 80px !important;
  width: 80px !important;
  min-width: 80px !important;
}

#main_row_About_results {
  border: 1px solid rgb(112, 113, 124);
  border-style: dashed;
}

p:focus,
h2:focus,
h3:focus,
a:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a href="main.php" class="nav-link">Summery</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="main.php" class="brand-link">
      <img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">ADMINS</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">Administrator Recons</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>
              <p>
                Dashboard
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="summery.php" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Admin Options</p>
                </a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Title</h1>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <br><br><br>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right" style="margin-right: 14.6%;">
              <!-- style="margin-right: 12%;" -->
              <li class="breadcrumb-item">My Breadcrum</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->


          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="max-width: 92.5%; width: 92.5%;">
            <!--style="max-width: 94%; width: 94%;"-->
            <h5>Title Item: <b>(*)</b> </h5>
            <input type="text" name="blog_nameInfo" id="blog_nameInfo" class="form-control" required>
            <br>
            <br>
          </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row" id="main_row_for_blogs">

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-12" style="max-width: 92.5%; width: 92.5%;">
            <!--style="max-width: 94%; width: 94%;"-->
            <div class="card" id="BlogEditorOptions">

              <div class="card-header">
                <h2>my title card</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="card-body" id="main_container_blog_section">

                <div class="row" id="main_row_About_results" style="display: block; position: relative !important; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

                  <!--this is the div that it's resizable-->

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2018 - MyBildingWall</strong>
    <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline-block">
      <b>Version</b> 1.0
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->

<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<script src="dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's working now, I had an error in a var, but I solved it. The code works good. Thanks for your help!